# Repeated replacement of characters in String

Tags: java, android, string

I'm trying to create an Android app which converts normal hex code to inverted one which is used in smali. Everything works perfectly except for that when I use the replace or replaceAll method on String, it even replaces the already replaced characters

For example,

```
String stringInvert = string.replace("F", "0")
    .replace("E" , "1")
    .replace("D" , "2")
    .replace("C" , "3")
    .replace("B" , "4")
    .replace("A" , "5")
    .replace("9" , "6")
    .replace("8" , "7")
    .replace("7" , "8")
    .replace("6" , "9")
    .replace("5" , "A")
    .replace("4" , "B")
    .replace("3" , "C") 
    .replace("2" , "D")
    .replace("1" , "E")
    .replace("0" , "F");
```

As you can see that first F is changed to 0, and similarly other letters are also changed, but later 0 is changed to F, which also changes the already changed F back to F. So, all in all, only the letters/numbers that are before 7 get inverted(as they are replaced after in the code) and others remain same due to dual inversion. I even tried replaceAll method, it gives the same result. So is there any other way or a work around to this problem?

Full code is here - http://pastebin.com/dB23JmQG

Sorry if the code is ugly, I did it in AIDE

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a `Map<Character, Character>` which will hold your mapping.

Then just iterate other the original `String`.

```
Map<Character, Character> m = new HashMap<>();
m.put('F','0');
....

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for(char c : originalString.toCharArray()){
   sb.append(map.get(Character.toUpperCase(c)));
} 
String finalString = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace with multiple steps like this:

```
String stringInvert = string
.replace("F", "null")
.replace("E" , "one")
.replace("D" , "two")
.replace("C" , "three")
.replace("B" , "four")
.replace("A" , "five")
.replace("9" , "six")
.replace("8" , "seven")
.replace("7" , "8")
.replace("6" , "9")
.replace("5" , "A")
.replace("4" , "B")
.replace("3" , "C") 
.replace("2" , "D")
.replace("1" , "E")
.replace("0" , "F")
.replace("null", "0")
.replace("one","1")
.replace("two","2" )
.replace("three","3" )
.replace("four","4" )
.replace("five","5" )
.replace("six","6" )
.replace("seven","7" );
```

Not nice and smart, but simple and working :)

Comment: Thank You. 

Works perfectly, and it's short and simple and doesn't require `much` modification in existing code :)

Answer (score 1):

You can solve the problem by replacing a hex digit to a temporary char before overwrite its position.

This is similar to the bubble sort algorithem.
For an example let's use the following string:
FF00F0

1. First turn the F into some character. '*' for example.
   The String is now **00*0
2. Turn 0 into F
   The String is now: **FF*F
3. Finally turn the * to 0.

There are much more efficient solutions but this one is simple and quick to program.

Answer (score 0):

This won't work for random mappings of characters to other characters, but since yours has a pattern you can make a function that will convert each character using their char/int values, for example:

```
static char convert(char c){
    int n = c;
    n = n - 70; // Adjust for capital F
    n = n * -1; // So earlier letters become larger numbers
    n += 48; // Adjust back to zero
    return (char)n;
}
```

This method will take any of the letter characters and return the equivalent number character (and the equivalent function for number characters should be clear), so just loop through converting each one individually.

If you care about speed, this should be pretty fast, especially if you can use char arrays instead of strings.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution could be using `Integer` API:

```
String stringToInvert = "A1F56C";

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : stringToInvert.toCharArray()) {
    sb.append(Integer.toHexString(15 - Integer.valueOf(c + "", 16)));
}

System.out.println(sb.toString().toUpperCase());
```

**Output:**

> 5E0A93